# Highcharts pie chart hide zero sector

Tags: javascript, highcharts

There is always thin sector for 0 (0%) value. 
How can I hide zero value sector on a pie chart.
http://jsfiddle.net/t0hgLx2n/

```
data: [
        ['Firefox',   100.0],
        ['Others',   0]
      ]
```

Remove this white line [image]
<sub>(source: [piccy.info](http://i.piccy.info/i9/c9481cdd8004e67104679cc5b697c36b/1423042478/56631/588856/image.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Is using `{ name: 'Others', y: 0, visible: false }` in the data-array considered a solution? Might require some more information on why it cannot just be removed from the data-array, or set to not visible upon creation, if these are not acceptable.

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work either http://jsfiddle.net/4yjn0g5h/

Comment: How does it "not work"? It doesn't show on the pie. What criteria must be met to work?

Comment: Is it the legend item you wish to remove on the picture (where the text "Others" is)?

Comment: legend item and white space

Answer (score 6):

This question could be resolved by two parts:

1. filter zero data

   ```
       data: [
           ['Firefox',   100.0],
           ['Others',   0]
       ].filter(function(d) {return d[1] > 0})
   ```
2. remove border in one-slice pie

   (please refer to [Border in one-slice pie #1828](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1828))

http://jsfiddle.net/Joe_Wu/sub2houn/

Answer (score -1):

---

It's been a while but if anyone stumbles upon this you have to update Highcharts to at least version 5.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/k54phzqm/)

Replace:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/4.0/highcharts.js"></script>
```

With:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/6.0/highcharts.js"></script>
```